# How to make image size match col text size in Bootsrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am not sure what I want to do is possible. I have a card layout with a single long text column on the left, and a single col on the right with several rows with an image in each row. When I use ctrl_shift_+ or ctrl_- to increase/decrease the text size, I want the images to increase/decrease in size so the column of images is always the same size as the column of text. Is that possible? How would I do that with Bootstrap 4?

I have attached 2 images that illustrate my problem. The images stay the same size as the text size changes when zooming in and out of the page.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: I understand and agree with your comment. I am working on creating a sample page in codepen because the production code is very large and spread over different files. I am not well versed in codepen, so there is a learning curve as well as a learning curve for Bootstrap 4 for me. I had hoped the screen shots would explain the issue well enough for some guidance. Thanks!